# Quadratic fit using sum of least squares without matrices

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, least-squares, sums-of-squares

I've been hunting around for examples using the sum of least squares + partial derivative method to fit a polynomial to a set of points but am completely stuck.  All the examples I've found involve matrices, but I am unfamiliar with how to use matrices.

Full disclosure, this is a homework problem for a multivariable calculus course.  Here's what I've tried:

Points
$(-2,4)$, $(-1,2)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$, and $(2,2)$ so n=5

My method:
$$f(a,b,c) = \sum{(y_i-(ax_i^2+bx_i+c))^2}$$
$$f(a,b,c) = \sum{y_i^2}-2a\sum{y_ix_i^2}=2b\sum{y_ix_i}-2c\sum{y_i}+a^2\sum{x_i^4}+2ab\sum{x_i^3}+2ac\sum{2_i^2}+2bc\sum{x_i}+b^2\sum{x_i^2}+5c^2$$

Find the partial derivatives for a, b, c and set to 0
$$f_a = -2\sum{y_ix_i^2}+2a\sum{x_i^4}+2b\sum{x_i^3}+2c\sum{x_i^2}$$
$$f_b = -2\sum{y_ix_i}+2a\sum{x_i^3}+2c\sum{x_i}+2b\sum{x_i^2}$$
$$f_c = -2\sum{y_i}+2a\sum{x_i^2}+2b\sum{x_i}+10c$$

Calculate all the sums:
$$\sum{x_i^4} = 34$$
$$\sum{x_i^3} = 0$$
$$\sum{x_i^2} = 10$$
$$\sum{x_i} = 0$$
$$\sum{y_i} = 10$$
$$\sum{y_ix_i} = -5$$
$$\sum{y_ix_i^2} = 27$$

But when I plug the sums in and set the partial deriatives to 0, I get the wrong answer:
$$68a+20c = 54$$
$$20b = -10$$
$$20a = 20$$

Which gives:
$$y = x^2-\frac{1}{2}x - \frac{7}{10}$$

I checked over the equations and I think they look right...but clearly they're not :/

Thank you!

Comment: The last equation is not $20a = 20$, but $20a +10c= 20$.

Comment: aaah it was so simple! D:  I needed the second set of eyes though, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

eep this was a simple algebra error!

Going to leave this up just in case anyone in the future is hunting around for an example of a polynomial fit using least squares without matrices.